# Multi-Step Next button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have to first click on the naviagtion bar before clicking on the Next button for it to work.  After the page has loaded, if I click on the next button it won't work.  But for the steps which follow, the buttons work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you init your wizard on `mousedown.wizard.data-api` you will, obviously, need to click on the menu to active the buttons.

But if you init the wizard on the load event

```
b(function () {

    var d = b(".wizard");

    if (!d.data("wizard")) {
        d.wizard(d.data());
    }

});
```

the buttons will work.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/v4awe8fp/3/)

Hope it may helps you